# How to initiate jquery on a new window.open and avoid "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with an object type="application/pdf" and two select tags that change the src of the object on change. Plus, there is an icon that opens a new window with this content (object + html select tags):

```
<div id="navegador_pdfs">

    <div id="btn_toggle_pdf_navigator">
        <a href="#" onclick="destacar();"><?php echo $this->Bootstrap->glyphicon('new-window'); ?></a>
    </div>

    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); color: #FFF; text-align: center;">
    Pasta Digital
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->select('linhas', 
                    [ 'Documentos: ' => $documentos, ' Ou: ' => [ '' => 'Ver Todos' ] ],
                    ['default' => $documento_id,
                    'class' => 'form-control truncated', 
                    'onchange' => " if( $.isNumeric($(this).val()) ) { "
                        . "$('#myPdf').attr('data', '" . $this->Url->build([ "controller" => "binario", "action" => "visualizar"]) . "/'+$(this).val()); "
                        . "} else { "
                        . "$('#myPdf').attr('data', '" . $this->Url->build([ "controller" => "binario", "action" => "ver-todos", "?" => [ 'numero_processo' => $numero_processo ]]) . "'); "
                        . "} "]);
    ?>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 15px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); color: #FFF; text-align: center;">
    Pasta Digital Externa
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->select('linhas', 
                    [ 'Documentos: ' => $documentosExternos, ' Ou: ' => [ '' => 'Ver Todos' ]  ],
                    ['class' => 'form-control truncated', 
                    'onchange' =>  " if( $(this).val() != '' ) { "
                        . "$('#myPdf').attr('data', '" . $this->Url->build([ "controller" => "solicitacao", "action" => "downloadDocumentoTj"]) . "/'+$(this).val()); "
                        . "} else { "
                        . "$('#myPdf').attr('data', '" . $this->Url->build([ "controller" => "solicitacao", "action" => "baixarTodosDocumentos", $cnj ]) . "'); "
                        . "} "
                        ]);
    ?>
    </div>
    <object id="myPdf" type="application/pdf" data="<?php echo ($documento_id > 0 ) ? $this->Url->build([ "controller" => "binario", "action" => "visualizar", $documento_id]) : "" ; ?>" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
</div>
```

And the script that opens this content on a new window:

```
function destacar(){

    const leftpos = screen.width / 2;
    const toppos = 0;

    var params  = 'width='+ (screen.width/2);
    params += ', height='+ (screen.height/1.2);
    params += ', top='+toppos+', left='+leftpos;
    params += ', fullscreen=yes';

    var divText = '<html><head>';
    divText += '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">';
    divText += '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/theme.css">';
    divText += '</head><body style="padding: 0px 5px;">';

    var myWindow = window.open('','',params);
    var doc = myWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(divText);

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '/js/jquery.min.js';

    $(doc.head).append(script);

    doc.write(document.getElementById("navegador_pdfs").outerHTML);

    doc.close();


    $('#form_novo_despacho').removeClass('col-md-6');
    $('#form_novo_despacho').addClass('col-md-12');
    $('#navegador_pdfs').hide();

    myWindow.onunload = function(){ 
        $('#form_novo_despacho').removeClass('col-md-12');
        $('#form_novo_despacho').addClass('col-md-6');
        $('#navegador_pdfs').show();
    };

}
```

And then, when i change the value of any select tags on the opened window, its possible to see on console the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (VM1774 nova:1)
```

I suppose that's jQuery is not initialized on this new recently opened window. Is there a way to initialize jQuery or is just another thing that i'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Jquery doesn't need initialization, it just needs to be loaded in before scripts that use it

Comment: Personally, I'd suppose the error comes from the `select`s' `onchange`, as the stack trace tells (`HTMLSelectElement.onchange`). One tries `$.isNumeric` and the other tries `$(this)`. Your main window (not the new one) does not have jQuery loaded. Or it's not loaded as `$` (I remember there was a "no conflict" option that loaded jQuery as `jQuery` and not as `$`).

Comment: Hi @StockOverflaw, thanks for your help, but at the main window, the onchange is working without errors. I'll try to test calling then by the same alias.

Comment: Oh, then I must misunderstand this: " when i change the value of any select tags, its possible to see on console the error". Aren't these select tags the ones that you show from your main window's code?

Comment: sorry, i'll edit my question, because the right sentence is "when i change the value of any select tags on the opened window ..."

Comment: Have you considered creating an event to wait for the script to load, *or*, preloading the script and just placing the response text inside of the script tag in the new window.

Comment: Hi @TravisJ i've tried to open a window and put content with ajax but this does not work either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't install using:

```
$(doc.head).append(script);
```

Use:

```
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);
```

or

```
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

You are trying to use `jQuery` to install `jQuery`.

---

You also might want to add your dependent code to the onload event of the script.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement

```
script.onload = function() {
 $('#form_novo_despacho').removeClass('col-md-6');
    $('#form_novo_despacho').addClass('col-md-12');
    $('#navegador_pdfs').hide();

    myWindow.onunload = function(){ 
        $('#form_novo_despacho').removeClass('col-md-12');
        $('#form_novo_despacho').addClass('col-md-6');
        $('#navegador_pdfs').show();
    };
}
```

or

```
script.addEventListener("load", function(event) {})
```